# how to set marginTop to the Div using jquery or javascript for IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a div tab as below in ascx page

```
  <div class="MC_LYT_LOS_Email_DialogCommands" id ="LOS_Email_DialogCommands">
  <Button runat="server" PhraseID="1427" ID="btnSend"  WaitStyle="BlockButton" />
  <Button runat="server" PhraseID="label:COMMON:PREVIEW" ID="btnPreview" Type="Secondary" />
    </div>`
```

and below is CSS:

```
.MC_LYT_LOS_Email_DialogCommands { margin-top: 25px !important; clear: none; }
```

this above works for all browsers except when changing the website language from english to spanish in IE8. I need to change the margin-Top from 25px to 5px. i tried below method none seem to working:

```
 var mydiv = document.getElementById("LOS_Email_DialogCommands");
  $('#mydiv').css('cssText', 'margin-top: 5px !important;');
  $('#mydiv').css('clear', 'none');
```

Before posting answers , it should only work in ie8.

Comment: have you tried `$('#LOS_Email_DialogCommands').css('margin-top', '5px');`

Comment: $(mydiv).css('margin-top', '5px');

Comment: @atmd - let me check, i think i have tried it once. anyway i will try

Comment: @SilencePeace its not working i tried it

Comment: @atmd what about !important and 'clear' ' none'

Comment: you might want to read the docs on jquery, selecting elements and the `css` method

Comment: @atmd can you give example

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, you could try:

```
 var mydiv = $("#LOS_Email_DialogCommands"); // selects the div
 mydiv.css('margin-top', '5px').css('clear', 'none'); //sets style
```

or you could use one css call and set both:

`mydiv.css({'margin-top':'5px', 'clear' : 'none'}); // sets both css props`

If you need to set a style as important, you'll need to use `attr`

`mydiv.attr('style', 'margin-top: 5px !important;'); // sets as !important`

Comment: mydiv.attr('style', 'margin-top: 5px !important;'); here where to add 'clear' : 'none' ?.

Comment: should this below code works :  mydiv.css({'clear' : 'none'});
                mydiv.attr('style', 'margin-top: 5px !important;');

Comment: if you are having trouble understanding the code, then I'd strongly suggest reading the docs on jquery and the mdn docs on javascript in general

Comment: depends what you mean by "should this below code works". how have you set `mydiv`? what are you seeing? where have you put the code? any errors?

Comment: i used "mydiv.attr('style', 'margin-top: 5px !important;');" in .js file , its not working , getting this error Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: like I said, how have you defined mydiv? with `document.getElement`, or `$('#`?

Comment: document.getElementById("LOSEmailDialogCommands").className = "MC_LYT_LOS_Email_DialogCommands_ES" is working where i added "MC_LYT_LOS_Email_DialogCommands_ES" in css with margin-top = 5px.

Comment: ok, `.css()` is jquery, you need to select an element with jquery using `$`. you can't use a jquery method unless you are calling it on a jquery object